# django: How to save a many to many field from view

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the following `save` method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url = slugify(self.name)

    # Saving creative if object is saved first time
    if self.reloadImages is True:
        print "Reload IMages"
        for img in self.creative_url.split("\n"):
            content = urllib2.urlopen(img).read()
            extra_image = ExtraImage()
            extra_image.img.save("%s.jpg" %(self.name), ContentFile(content), save=False)
            extra_image.save()
            self.extra_imgs.add(extra_image)
            #print self.extra_imgs.all()
    #self.reloadImages = False
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I expect it to create an `ExtraImage` objects (which consists from `ImageField`). And add it to the ManyToMany `extra_img` field of the current model....

It's strange it seems that method makes its job correctly, after page refresh I don't see anything in `extra_imgs` field. (And `ExtraImage` items are actually created)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you add images

```
self.extra_imgs.add(extra_image)
```

before `self` is created in your database

```
super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So how do I rewrite my code? Do I need to call super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 2 times? Or?

Comment: Just put call 'super' before if-condition

Answer (score 0):

To add on to San4ez's answer, this problem (the fact that you have to save an object before you save its dependencies, and the dependency doesn't always go the way you expect it to) frustrated me when I first started learning Django.

If you have large object graphs (or even small ones :) ) and you don't want to deal with this manually, check out [Django ORM Tools](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2305/) which has a GraphSaver class which will automatically detect dependencies and save the graph in the right order.

Comment: Tried this as well. But in case I use GraphSaver.save(self) in a save method I am getting a recursion loop...